# Guess the object game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in python and had a class assignment to create a script that resembles the 20-Questions game. I started on this so far:

```
# 20-Questions
#first question
q1= raw_input("Is it on the floor")
#continuation for first quesion "yes" answers
if 'yes' in q1:
  print("It is on floor")
if 'yes' in q1:
  q2a =raw_input("Is it smooth")
#continuation for first quesion "no" answers
if 'no' in q1:
  print("It is not on the floor")
if 'no' in q1:
  q2b=raw_input("Is it on the wall?")
#continuation for second quesion "yes yes" answers
if 'yes' in q2a:
  print("It is smooth")
if 'yes' in q2a:
    q3a=raw_input("Is it floor?")
#continuation for second quesion "yes no" answers
if 'no' in q2a:
  print("It is not smooth")
if 'no' in q2a:
    q3b=raw_input("Is it electronic?")
#continuation for second quesion "no yes" answers
if 'yes' in q2b:
  print("It is on wall")
if 'yes' in q2b:
    q3c=raw_input("Is it a poster?")
#continuation for second quesion "no no" answers
if 'no' in q2b:
  print("It is not on wall")
if 'no' in q2b:
    q3d=raw_input("Is it on the ceiling?")
#continuation for third question "yes yes yes"
if 'yes' in q3a:
  print("It is floor, floor is good")
#continuation for third question "yes yes no"
if 'no' in q3a:
  print("It must be desk,then...")
#continuation for third question "yes no yes"
if 'yes' in q3b:
  print("It is computer, yes?, everthing electronic is computer")
#continuation for third question "yes no no"
if 'no' in q3b:
  print("I dont know, lot of non-smooth and non-electronic things, not have enough time to code in")
#continuation for third question "no yes yes"
if 'yes' in q3c:
    q3c=raw_input("Poster show great many things, so guess is good right?")
#continuation for third question "no yes no"
if 'no' in q3c:
    q3c=raw_input("If poster not on wall, what is? Nail, cabniet, hole?; they not matter, poster matters")
#continuation for third question "no no yes"
if 'yes' in q3d:
    q3d=raw_input("If on ceiling, then it must be light!")
#continuation for third question "no no no"
if 'no' in q3d:
    q3d=raw_input("So it is not on celing, wall, or celing, where is it?; Your item must be invisible...")
else:
  raw_input("you silly goose!, it is yes or no question!")
```

It gives me errors in some variables not being defined, but I cannot define them as I have to lead the user to certain questions to predict their object.

Comment: always put in question code and FULL error message.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to repeat `if 'yes' in q1:` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having trouble is that when you only ask and set the question/variable corresponding with q2a.  The variable q2b is still checked to be yes or no answer.  The result is you asking python to check if q2b is true or false even when the person has only been asked the question for q2a.  Thus the variable isn't set and python gives you an error.

Solution:
The organization of your code is a bit messy.
Rethink the way you are organizing this to make sure that you don't check variables that haven't been set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, so would I need to put my code in a way that variables are set only when needed?